# The dark: class does not exist. If dark: is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a @layer directive

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-3

I am using `tailwindcss version 3.2.6`.

I tried this in different ways but it didn't work.
After trying it in VScode I'm getting an error like this-

```
The `dark:` class does not exist. If `dark:` is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a `@layer` directive.
```

When I try to add this in `global.css`

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


@layer base {
    body {
        @apply max-w-2xl mx-auto px-4 bg-white text-black;
        @apply dark: bg-black dark:text-white
    }
}
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"
  ],
  darkMode: "class",
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        "sans": ['var(--font-rubik)']
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [require("daisyui")],
}
```

**app.tsx**

```
import "@/styles/globals.css"
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { ThemeProvider } from "next-themes";

import { rubik } from "@/Fonts";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider attribute="class">
      <main className={`${rubik.variable} font-sans`}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </main>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

Why I am facing that error?

Answer (score 4):

If vs code does the spacing when autosaving make sure to:

1. Change the language mode for that file, you can find it in the Status Bar [Status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06yin.png)
2. Select Tailwind CSS as a language mode[Changing the language mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dbWH.png)

You are good to go!

Answer (score 3):

`dark: bg-black` is invalid. It should be `dark:bg-black` without the space.

Answer (score 2):

Fix in three steps

1. Install this plugin if using VS-code, Tailwind CSS IntelliSense. [Screenshot with pointers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI56E.png)
2. Click on your status bar language model tab; it often has languages depending on the current file (e.g. CSS, Javascript,
   Typescript, etc). It's always at the base of your workspace, where
   You often have prettier and other configurable quick links).
3. Search for TailwindCSS and select.